# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext-How to test main class of Spring-boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have a spring-boot application where my `@SpringBootApplication` starter class looks like a standard one and getting Caused by:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed
>   to parse configuration class [com.abct.ECRRestServer];
>
> nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open
>   ServletContext resource [/application.properties]

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ECRRestServerTest {

    @Test
    public void contextTest() {

    }
}
```

Encountering below issue.

> 2019-04-27 18:51:25.732 ERROR 15096 --- [           main]
>
> o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while
>   allowing TestExecutionListener
>   [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@78e117e3]
>   to prepare test instance [com.abct.ECRRestServerTest@16ecee1]
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>
> Failed
>   to parse configuration class [com.abct.ECRRestServer]; nested
>   exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open
>   ServletContext resource [/applicati
>
> on.properties]

Comment: Do you have `application.properties` file in your project?

Comment: If you have `application.properties` file in some other locations (instead of `src/main/resources`), add the file path in environment variable in your IDE.

Comment: application.properties on class path , spring boot application reading the properties,only test having issue.

Comment: test  was encountering an error when I integrated some other spring boot application with my micro service(Spring boot application) .

Comment: @Bhanu could you please be more specific? My spring boot application is also a microservice.